# Launch an external PixelSense application programmatically

Tags: external, launch, pixelsense

Is there a possibility to programmatically launch an external PixelSense application in Surface Mode, out of my own PixelSense application?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to verify this for the Surface Shell on Pixelsense, but on the Surface v1 you could do that as long as the application you wanted to launch was registered by the shell.

If the application you want to launch is your own you could also put it in a usercontrol and compile it into a dll so it can be loaded within the calling application.